# Adding .active class to div when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's tab system for a "set your account up" page and at the top of the page I have the different steps which are displayed at the top of the page above the tab-panes. I am trying to make it so when someone clicks an option in step one it will load the step two tab and add the active class to the appropriate steps div. I got this working, but can't figure out how to highlight the step you're currently on. So if you're on step one which is to finish your basic profile, then click save and continue at the bottom, it loads the next tab/step and adds the active class to the appropriate div for that step.

So, essentially I want to have the steps hand off the "active" class similar to how the bootstrap default tabs function where the one you're on is the one highlighted, except these "steps" divs aren't actually part of the tab system, just need to be affected by it.

Thank you!

[image: tabs and steps]

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: I don't know how my current code is relevant? I'm just trying to find the best solution for adding a class to another div when a button is clicked.

Comment: `$("#mybutton").click(function(){ $("#anotherdiv").addClass("active"); });`

Comment: Sounds like something that `Bootstrap Tour` does already. Check it out at http://bootstraptour.com/

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I added an image to better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: Show us a demo at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to make it so when someone clicks an option in step one it will load the step two tab and add the active class to the appropriate steps div.

Because you didn't provide any markup. I'm assuming you don't know where to start. All of this can be put together if you go through the Bootstrap documentation.

First thing is to setup the tab markup using the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute.

```
<div class="text-center"> 
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3</a>
</div>
```

Next, setup your tab-content with your individual panes that includes your buttons.

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="step1" class="tab-pane active">
     <div>
        <h1>Step 1</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="text-right"> 
         <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#">Next</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Use the example provided by Bootstrap, `shown.bs.tab`. *This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown.*

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

> So if you're on step one which is to finish your basic profile, then click save and continue at the bottom, it loads the next tab/step and adds the active class to the appropriate div for that step.

Create a click event to listen for the button click and show the next pane.

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    var nextId = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').next().attr("id");
    $('[href=#' + nextId + ']').tab('show');
});
```

Here's a fiddle with it all put together for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/kmx4zx6n/

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you so much for taking your time to explain this!

Comment: is there a way to do this so the "steps" don't work as links? I don't want people to be able to continue without pressing the actual continue button where it'll run form validation before they continue. I feel like if I remove the links in your code for the steps, it will break this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Commented on wrong answer: *Remove the `data-toggle="tab"` from each link and change the function from `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` to just `$('a')`. You can also add an ID to the div container and target it like `$('#id > a')`. Here's the updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/kmx4zx6n/1/. Only the buttons in the tab-pane work now.*

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery `addClass` and `removeClass`

**JQUERY**

```
$('.main-class a').on('click',function(){
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-class text-center"> 
 <a class="btn btn-default active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
    background-color:green !important;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/P1XvATZ98Y)

Comment: This is close, but what I'm looking for is the "step" buttons you made to not be actual buttons. The buttons that move the page to the next tab would inside each tab pane. the step buttons you demonstrated wouldn't be actual buttons, but indicators of what step you're on.

Answer (score 0):

In css use something like this:

`.step div { background-color: red; }
.step.active div { background-color: blue; }`

It's what you want?